# Verificar navegador do usuário em PHP

Tags: php, navegador-de-internet

Como verifico se o usuário esta usando o navegador Internet Explorer, versao 10 para baixo, para que eu possa exibir uma mensagem para ele atualizar aquilo antes de entrar no meu site?

Comment: aqui na versão inglês tem a sua resposta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302302/php-if-internet-explorer-6-7-8-or-9

Comment: +1 pelo "aquilo" =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizei o seguinte código:

```
/* VERIFICAR NAVEGADOR */
function Navegador() {

    $MSIE = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"MSIE");
    $Firefox = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Firefox");
    $Mozilla = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mozilla");
    $Chrome = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Chrome");
    $Chromium = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Chromium");
    $Safari = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Safari");
    $Opera = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Opera");

    if ($MSIE == true) { $navegador = "IE"; }
    else if ($Firefox == true) { $navegador = "Firefox"; }
    else if ($Mozilla == true) { $navegador = "Firefox"; }
    else if ($Chrome == true) { $navegador = "Chrome"; }
    else if ($Chromium == true) { $navegador = "Chromium"; }
    else if ($Safari == true) { $navegador = "Safari"; }
    else if ($Opera == true) { $navegador = "Opera"; }
    else { $navegador = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; }

    return $navegador;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Olá amigo veja um exemplo:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$browser = get_browser();
print_r($browser);
?>
```

veja funcionando nesse link : [Exemplo](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_misc_get_browser)

Answer (score 2):

Ajuste código da [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5302437/3834363) *SO-En*:

```
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-10]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    // aqui é igual ou menor que 10
}
else
{
    // aqui maior que 10
}
```

Referência Pergunta: [SO-EN - PHP: If internet explorer 6, 7, 8 , or 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5302302/3834363)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` e criar uma função de verificação:

```
    function navegador($user_agent){
    if(preg_match('/rv:9.0/i',$user_agent)) {
    return "ok";
    }
}
```

Com isso feito, só aplicar na página web:

```
$verifica = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$executa = navegador($verifica);
$ok = "ok";
if($ok == $executa){
//Código para o aviso do navegador IE9.0
} else {
//demais navegadores 
}
```

Note que você pode modificar o `preg_match` pra identificar qualquer navegador.

Answer (score 1):

Velho, é interessante que saibamos identificar o navegador e claro, informar ao usuário, mas o mais importante é adaptar o sistema para que ele funcione em TODOS navegadores possíveis...

Infelizmente não podemos prever qual a máquina que o usuário vai usar pra acessar o sistema, veja aqui no caso da empresa que trabalho, a maioria do nosso público-alvo tem acesso ao Firefox 28 pra baixo e ao IE8. Agora que ta começando a entrar o Chrome...

Recentemente tivemos uma dor de cabeça pra adaptar pra que funcionasse tudo em todos navegadores.....

Pesquisa sobre Web Design Responsivo e começa a ler artigos a respeito.

Uma tática não muito fácil de ser implementada, eu desenvolvi a algum tempo, utilizar CSS pra embelezar a página de acordo com o navegador, claro não é tão completo assim, tem alguns erros, ainda mais no Opera e no Safari que usam o mesmo USER AGENT do Chrome :

```
#testehack{
    /* Cor preta para todos os navegadores */
    /*color:#000;*/
    /* Cor rosa para o IE7 */ 
    *background-image:url("imgs/ie7.jpg");
    *height: 330px;
    *width: 590px;
    /* Cor preta para o IE6 */
    _background-image:url("imgs/ie6.jpg");
}
```

/* Hack para o Internet Explorer 8 */

```
#testehack{
      background-image:url("imgs/ie8.png")\0/;
      height: 290px\0/;
      width: 284px\0/;
}
```

/* Hack para o Internet Explorer 9 */

```
@media all and (min-width:0) {
    #testehack{
        background:url("imgs/ie9.jpg");
        height: 310px\0/;
        width: 319px\0/;
    }
}
```

/* Hack para Firefox */

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
      #testehack{
            background-image:url("imgs/fix.png");
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
      }
}
```

/* Hack para Chrome e Safari */

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
      #testehack{
            background-image:url("imgs/chr-saf.jpg");
            height: 194px;
            width: 259px;
      }
}
```

/* Hack para Opera */

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000), not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
    #testehack{
        background-image:url("imgs/ope.png");
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho o uso desse iframe possa te ajudar.

```
<iframe src="http://www.whatismybrowser.com/feature/iframe?capabilities=true" width="600" height="370" style="border: none; overflow: visible !important; top:50%; left:50%; margin-left:-300px; margin-top:-185px; position:absolute;" id="wimb-detection-iframe"></iframe>
```

Ele retorna, se os cookies do navegador estao ativos, se o javascript está habilidado, qual versão do flash, se tem java instalado. O navegador e versão do mesmo e qual sistema operacional.

Answer (score 0):

Corrigido:

```js
function Navegador() {
    $MSIE = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"MSIE");
    $MSIE2 = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Trident");
    $Firefox = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Firefox");
    $Mozilla = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mozilla");
    $Chrome = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Chrome");
    $Chromium = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Chromium");
    $Safari = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Safari");
    $Opera = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Opera");

    if ($MSIE == true) { $navegador = "IE"; }
    if ($MSIE2 == true) { $navegador = "IE"; }
    else if ($Firefox == true) { $navegador = "Firefox"; }
    else if ($Mozilla == true) { $navegador = "Firefox"; }
    else if ($Chrome == true) { $navegador = "Chrome"; }
    else if ($Chromium == true) { $navegador = "Chromium"; }
    else if ($Safari == true) { $navegador = "Safari"; }
    else if ($Opera == true) { $navegador = "Opera"; }
    else { $navegador = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; }

    return $navegador;
}
```

Comment: para quê o MSIE2?

Answer (score 0):

Segue outra forma de fazer isso

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Verifica CHROME</title>

  <!-- Inserir este SCRIPT no inicio da pagina ou no header -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
    if (!isChrome) 
    { 
      window.location.href = "PAGINA_COM_MENSAGEM_DE_ERRO_POR_NAO_SER_CHROME.html";
    } 

    document.body.innerHTML = output;
  </script>
  <!-- fim do script -->

</head>

<body>
Você está no chrome então OK pode seguir
#Código vai aqui! 
</body>
</html>
```